# I am getting an error as invalid template file when i tried to add a custom payment method in custom module file

Tags: module, template, admin-panel, magento-2.2.5

Invalid template file: `'RW_CustomPaymentMethod::info/custompaymentmethod.phtml'` in module: 'RW_CustomPaymentMethod' block's name: 'info\custompaymentmethod_0'

Should we declare this template somewhere else too.
And also in view folder, i have only adminhtml folder no frontend folder as this payment method has to be only from admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create  `custompaymentmethod.phtml` at frontend folder.As you have trying to build for both and frontend.

Comment: No, i don't want the payment method to be used for customer from storefront. Still should i create frontend folder?

Comment: yes, you have to use

Comment: How do I store this value in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create the phtml file into below location.

```
app/code/RW/CustomPaymentMethod/view/frontend/templates/info/custompaymentmethod.phtml
```

**Note :** if you do not want to offer customer for frontend, then you can leave this phtml file blank.